# The page contains too many server redirects

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

My site works fine when I visit it from desktop. But when i visit it from any mobile devices, like android phone, iphone and ipad, it doesn't work. it gives me

```
error:The page contains too many server redirects
```

and also when i visit it from mobile devices the url changes automatically.

```
it changes to: http://mypage.com/?area=Mobile.
```

how come it changes !! i didn't write any code that can force it to change to that url.
I have tried google but didn't find any specific answer...any idea guys??

### EDIT

The problem is solved now. Thanks guys for the comments.
There was two helper classes that was redirecting the page to a mobile page which does not exists. and hence creating an infinite loop.

Comment: can you share the site's link? Are you using any outside scripts or plugins?

Comment: Some good places to start are the `Application_Start` and `Session_Start` methods of Global.asax.cs - dig into any filters referenced there that might be the source of your auto-redirect. It's also not a bad idea to peek in Web.config in case there's a redirect section defined. For a less elegant but still potentially effective approach, you can try a solution-wide search for 'Mobile' or 'redirect'.

Comment: Any chance you are using 51Degrees.mobi library?